# Bash get value of matching substring in a long string

Tags: bash, jenkins, awk, sed, jq

I'm working on a bash script and having hard time extracting value from a matching substring.
I cannot share curl command as it has sensitive information but updating i value(1)(updated to mimic real value) that I'm having problem with. jq gives parse error

```
curl -s -g "$line" | jq -c '.allBuilds[]' | while read i; do
   job_name=$(echo "$i" | jq .fullDisplayName | tr -d '»' | tr -s " " | sed 's/ /,/g' | tr -d '"')
done
```

expected output
`Hello,Java,World,master,#47`

I get expected output on most of the i values but some error out

Below are sample i values.

1

```
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","actions":[{"_class":"hudson.model.CauseAction"},{},{"_class":"hudson.model.ParametersAction","parameters":[{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"environment","value":"DE"},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"update","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"black","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"description","value":"DE"},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"number","value":""},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"config","value":"{ "E": "DE", "Exp": "1111", "Pr": "D", "Man": { "Se": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/Se-B8SKMz", "OR": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/OR-kvJ2lJ", "AR": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:A/DE/SA/rds", "User": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/mUixbWY", "sales": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/saELY", "vau": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/vNRR7BO", "sc": "", "exAd": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:BA/A/ExyBoYL", "exp": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:BA/A/Exl67GE", "sec": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/Secle06a", "Secu": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:111111111111:secret:DE/A/Seia" }, "s3": { "buckets": { "hello": { "name": "helloDEBA", "region": "region", "account": "111111111111" }, "mlt": { "name": "sacdhbd", "region": "region", "account": "111111111111" }, "devo": { "name":"devvvvv", "region": "region", "account": "5555555" } } }, "roles": { "lam": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/lam", "lambd": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/lambd", "la": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/lam", "la": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/la", "la": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/la","lasds": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/lafgg", "lafdg": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/dfsdv", "acc": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/acc" }, "vpc": { "subnets": { "private": { "1a": "subnet-111111", "1b": "subnet-22222", "1c": "subnet-33333" } }, "securityGroupIds": { "lambda": "sg-1111" }, "endpoints": { "e": "" }, "links": { "b": "" } }, "securi": { "level": "FAILURE", "s": true }, "log": "debug", "se": "hello.com", "sa": { "env": "--DE" }, "lam": { "sss": { "environment": { "variables": { "test": "hello.com", "PhoneNumber": "11111" } } } } }"},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"scan","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"ch","value":false}]},{"_class":"jenkins.scm.A.SCMRevisionAction"},{},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData"},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.GitTagAction"},{},{},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl"},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData"},{},{},{},{},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.RestartDeclarativePipelineAction"},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"},{},{},{},{}],"fullDisplayName":"Hello » Java » World » master #25","id":"25","number":25,"timestamp":1575582153372}
```

2

```
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun","actions":[{"_class":"hudson.model.CauseAction"},{"_class":"hudson.model.ParametersAction","parameters":[{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"helo-world","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"environment","value":"hello"},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"config","value":""},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"description","value":""},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"hello","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"hello2","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.BooleanParameterValue","name":"scan","value":false},{"_class":"hudson.model.StringParameterValue","name":"hello3","value":""}]},{"_class":"jenkins.scm.api.SCMRevisionAction"},{},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData"},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.GitTagAction"},{},{},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl"},{"_class":"hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData"},{},{},{},{},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.actions.RestartDeclarativePipelineAction"},{},{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.views.FlowGraphAction"},{},{},{},{}],"fullDisplayName":"Hello»Java»World»master#21","id":"21","number":21,"timestamp":1574705384077}
```

I'm trying to extract fullDisplayName value and I have tried some options like

```
printf '%s\n' "$i" | grep fullDisplayName
```

printf '%s\n'  gives output in new lines when tried in shell but in script its different behavior

```
{}
{}
{}]
fullDisplayName:Hello » Java » World » master #25
id:25
number:25
timestamp:1575582153372
```

Comment: Why would you grep for `fullDisplayName` and expect to get output `"Hello»Java»World»master#22","id":"22","number":22,"timestamp":1574705541773` which obviously doesn't contain the string `fullDisplayName` that you grepped for?

Comment: Can you just post output of `curl` command?

Comment: The `"`s in each `""` pair around `$line` in `curl -s -g ""$line""` are canceling each other out and so doing nothing. `""$line""` is exactly the same as just `$line` since the `""` on either side of it is just a null string. I think/hope you meant `"$line"` with individual double quotes on either side (just like you did with `"$i"` later in your script) so you're quoting `$line` instead of just redundantly putting a null string on either side of it.

Comment: @EdMorton Edited my post(have been trying different options).

Comment: You can't put formatted text in a comment. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and do [what @anubhava requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943209/bash-get-value-of-matching-substring-in-a-long-string?noredirect=1#comment111308622_62943209) so we can help you.

Comment: @oguzismail some are not valid json as I mentioned in the post

Comment: If the `curl` output isn't valid `json` then don't try to use a `json` parser like `jq` on it. Once we see the `curl` output then we might be able to make sense of this and help you.

Comment: Hang on - are you saying the `curl` output isn't valid json or the value of `$i` inside the while read loop isn't valid json? Whatever it is, please [edit] your question to clarify and, again, provide that `curl` output.

Comment: `full_display_name="$(jq -j .fullDisplayName <<<"$JSON_ANSWER")"`

Comment: @EdMorton updated post with valid i value that is giving jq error. Its not a valid json so I cannot jq anymore so checking for other options

Comment: Again (and for the last time), it's not the `i` values we need to see it's the output of `curl`. The `i` values are just slices of newline separated text after `jq` has tried to parse what may or may not be valid json input and generated what may or may not be blocks of multi-line json, and then `while read` has potentially corrupted some of that by not being called with the required default values, reading parts of multi-line json one line at a time, etc...

Comment: Please also state clearly in your question which call to `jq` you're referring to when you say `jq gives parse error` - is it the `jq -c '.allBuilds[]'`or the `jq .fullDisplayName` or both? what **exactly** is the error message and which block of text is it referring to?

Comment: @EdMorton jq .fullDisplayName gives parse error not jq -c '.allBuilds[]'

I will add curl output

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943209/bash-get-value-of-matching-substring-in-a-long-string?noredirect=1#comment111308892_62943209), please [edit] your question to include all relevant information, don't spread it out among comments where we may miss it. When you do add the `curl` output please make sure it's minimal (e.g. no more than about a dozen lines) but truly represents your real data and that you provide it as text, not a link or an image.

Comment: Feel free to edit the actual `curl` output to remove sensitive or irrelevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It would appear that you should be using `read -r`.
2. It also appears that it would be much simpler if you focused on using curl and jq to extract the information, without any grep or tr invocation and without any shell looping.  Assuming you can arrange for the output of `curl` to be valid JSON(*), a single invocation of jq along the following lines should do the job:

```
jq -c '.allBuilds[] | .fullDisplayName | gsub("»";"")'
```

(*) To check whether the output of `curl` is valid, you can pipe the output of your `curl` command into `jq empty`:

```
curl ... | jq empty
```

Comment: thank you, read -r in curl did the trick.

without r, .allBuilds[] is not a valid json